# How to debug "Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command" when sending to GMail in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, email, smtp

[image]

After I use print debugger to check whether it's sent or not, and here's what I got in return:

```
bool(false) 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP t8sm1776565pgr.21 - gsmtp 
hello: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [45.116.123.5]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. t8sm1776565pgr.21 - gsmtp 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
Date: Fri, 2 Feb 2018 13:02:25 +0530
To: demo@example.com
From: "MyWebsite" <demo@example.com>
Return-Path: <demo@example.com>
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?How=20to=20send=20email=20vi?==?UTF-8?Q?a=20SMTP=20?= =?UTF-8?Q?server=20in=20CodeIgniter?=
Reply-To: <demo@example.com>
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
X-Sender: demo@example.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <5a741409bc741@gmail.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0


Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_5a741409bc741"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
Your email application may not support this format.

--B_ALT_5a741409bc741
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Sending email via SMTP serverThis email has sent via SMTP server from
CodeIgniter application.


--B_ALT_5a741409bc741
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

=3Ch1=3ESending email via SMTP server=3C/h1=3E=3Cp=3EThis email has sent vi=
a SMTP server from CodeIgniter application.=3C/p=3E

--B_ALT_5a741409bc741--
```

When I changed the smtp_port to 465 and I got in response like

```
bool(false) 
hello: F
The following SMTP error was encountered: F
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
Date: Fri, 2 Feb 2018 13:12:43 +0530
To: demo@example.com
From: "MyWebsite" <demo@example.com>
Return-Path: <demo@example.com>
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?How=20to=20send=20email=20vi?==?UTF-8?Q?a=20SMTP=20?= =?UTF-8?Q?server=20in=20CodeIgniter?=
Reply-To: <demo@example.com>
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
X-Sender: demo@example.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <5a7416736d6ea@gmail.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0


Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_5a7416736d6ea"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
Your email application may not support this format.

--B_ALT_5a7416736d6ea
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Sending email via SMTP serverThis email has sent via SMTP server from
CodeIgniter application.


--B_ALT_5a7416736d6ea
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

=3Ch1=3ESending email via SMTP server=3C/h1=3E=3Cp=3EThis email has sent vi=
a SMTP server from CodeIgniter application.=3C/p=3E

--B_ALT_5a7416736d6ea--
```

I have hidden my email id in this question for security purposes.

I find so many code examples that they wanted to change local php.ini and sendmail.ini files to send emails but I think that's not the requirement to send mail using smtp.

I also use the PHPmailer lib and it works for smtp mail, but why CodeIgniter email lib for SMTP is not working? Which PHP version is supported for this CodeIgniter SMTP settings?

Comment: Please [read this](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) and replace your image of code with the text version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
                             $ci = get_instance();
                             $ci->load->library('email');
                             $config['protocol']  = "smtp";
                             $config['smtp_host'] = "mail.google.com";
                             $config['smtp_port'] = "26";
                             $config['smtp_user'] = "********@gmail.com";
                             $config['smtp_pass'] = "************";
                             $config['charset']   = "utf-8";
                             $config['mailtype']  = "html";
                             $config['newline']   = "\r\n";

                             $ci->email->initialize($config);

                             $ci->email->from('*********@gmail.com');

                             $email_body = "Sending Email from server.";

                            $this->email->to($userEmail']);
                            $this->email->subject('Email Subject');
                            $this->email->message($email_body);
                            $email = $this->email->send();
```

Comment: still not work i get this error  @Muahmmad Umar Bilal

The following SMTP error was encountered: 10060 A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

Comment: Oh. I forgot to tell you that this will not work on localhost. It is working fine on live server in my project.

Comment: then what is the use of smtp ?

Comment: using email lib and protocol  = mail will be used in live server not localhost

Comment: This link could help you.  https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-gmail-smtp/

Comment: and smtp used for both localhost and live server .

Comment: I think this could be done with change the port. Try other ports  25 or 587 etc. Also configure php.ini file.

Comment: i also tried the sendmail.ini file changing and its works in local but that is not  the correct solution . because of what if i transfer my code to live server or another pc then what , ? do i have to change again that settings ? get my point ?

Comment: Common SMTP ports:

SMTP - port 25 or 2525 or 587
Secure SMTP (SSL / TLS) - port 465 or 25 or 587, 2526 (Elastic Email)

Comment: please don't bother sendmail.ini in it. That is not a problem. The problem could be in php.ini file.

Comment: is there any way to use smtp without changing the php.ini file ?

Comment: That code is perfectly fine for me. I am not sure about the php.ini configuration should be done or not for live server.  It might be possible that it will work without php.ini configuration. You should conduct a test on live server then move further.

Comment: It could be possible. Try to test it first. That's it.

Comment: do you know phpmailer class ?

Comment: No. I did not use php mailer function.

Answer (score 0):

Google has disabled use of less secure apps since March 2022. You may Create & use App Passwords instead, as provided in this link https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833#zippy=%2Cwhy-you-may-need-an-app-password

Also add the following codeigniter library https://github.com/ivantcholakov/codeigniter-phpmailer